# Qt C++ FireBase Update Unique Value

Tags: c++, firebase, qt, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database in FreeBase.

There is a database structure as in the photo [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XFD8.png).

When I want to make changes in the database, I need to change all the data, but I want to change only one data. The codes I wrote below update all the data.

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

request.setUrl(QUrl("https://xxx/Printers/Syra123/3333.json"));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json"));

QVariantMap newPrinter;

    newPrinter["AvailableModels"] = value.getAvailableModels();
    newPrinter["CurrentBedTemp"] = value.getCurrentBedTemp();
    newPrinter["CurrentNozzleTemp"] = value.getCurrentNozzleTemp();
    newPrinter["Percentage"] = value.getPercentage();
    newPrinter["PrintedTime"] = value.getPrintTime();
    newPrinter["PrinterStatus"] = value.getPrinterStatus();
    newPrinter["PrintingStatus"] = value.getPrintingStatus();
    newPrinter["SelectedBedTemp"] = value.getSelectedBedTemp();
    newPrinter["SelectedModel"] = value.getSelectedModel();
    newPrinter["SelectedNozzleTemp"] = value.getSelectedNozzleTemp();
    newPrinter["SelectedPositionX"] = value.getSelectedNozzleX();
    newPrinter["SelectedPositionY"] = value.getSelectedNozzleY();
    newPrinter["SelectedPositionZ"] = value.getSelectedNozzleZ();
    newPrinter["SelectedPrintSpeed"] = value.getSelectedPrintSpeed();
    newPrinter["SelectedPrintingStatus"] = value.getSelectedPrintingStatus();
    newPrinter["StartingTime"] = value.getStartingTime();

    QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(newPrinter);

    manager->put(request,jsonDoc.toJson());
```

When I write and send only one data, it destroys all other values ​​in the database and only the data I sent remains. How can I change only the data I want without deleting the data in the DataBase?

Answer (score 0):

You have to restructure you codes, create another class that will hold values / data of getAvailableModels(),  getCurrentBedTemp(), getCurrentNozzleTemp(), getPercentage() e.t.c from QNetworkReply *reply, reply->readAll() through (get) to populate QLineedit(s), then modify the desire QLineedit and put to update.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).